# Is there a bot menu in Telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm building an app with [Telethon](https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and almost finished it. Now there is some beauty left to be made and I found out that there is no good explanation in the internet (and docs too) how to make bot's menu.

Year or two ago I have built another bot with [TeleBot](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/) and It provides a good solution for it using `types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup`. I can see how Telethon documentaion mentions `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` but still I can't get my bot's menu done.

Just to be clear, what I want to do look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, I've found out that I was using wrong Button's type (`inline` instead of `text`). Working code:

```
from telethon import events, Button

bot = ...

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start'))
async def handle_start_command(event):
    markup = event.client.build_reply_markup([
        [Button.text('First button')],
        [Button.text('Second button')]
    ])
    await event.respond("Hello!", buttons=markup)
```

Result looks like this:

[image]

[Documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.button.Button) says that:

> You can use `inline`, `switch_inline`, `url` and `auth` together to create
> inline buttons (under the message).
>
> You can use `text`, `request_location`, `request_phone` and `request_poll`
> together to create a reply markup (replaces the user keyboard).